# How to remove "@attributes" when using simplexml_load_string() to convert XML to JSON

Tags: php, json, xml

What I need is,

[image]

but what i got is,

[image]

How can I remove "@attributes" from the result.

Comment: are you trying to convert a xml string into json object ?   if yes,   try this           $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$json = json_encode($xml);

Comment: I have converted it already. but the result isn't what I need.

Comment: Could you mind sharing xml string you are trying to convert ?

Comment: I have this problem too :(

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me:

```
// Cleans up ugly JSON data by removing @attributes tag
function cleanup_json ($ugly_json) {
   if (is_object($ugly_json)) {
      $nice_json = new stdClass();
      foreach ($ugly_json as $attr => $value) {
         if ($attr == '@attributes') {
            foreach ($value as $xattr => $xvalue) {
              $nice_json->$xattr = $xvalue;
            }
         } else {
            $nice_json->$attr = cleanup_json($value);
         }
      }
      return $nice_json;
   } else if (is_array($ugly_json)) {
      $nice_json = array();
      foreach ($ugly_json as $n => $e) {
        $nice_json[$n] = cleanup_json($e);
      }
      return $nice_json;
   } else {
      return $ugly_json;
   }
}

// Convert XML to JSON
function convert_to_json ($xml_string) {
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
   $ugly_json = json_decode(json_encode($xml));
   $nice_json = cleanup_json($ugly_json);
   return json_encode($nice_json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It may work for you.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
$json = json_encode($xml, true);
```

Comment: thanks you Answer,but I got the same result . "@attribute" still exist.